# Backbone this.el is undefined in local

Tags: backbone.js

In index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  </html>
```

in index.js

```
  (function($){
    // **ListView class**: Our main app view.
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $('body'), // attaches `this.el` to an existing element.
      // `initialize()`: Automatically called upon instantiation. Where you make all types of bindings, _excluding_ UI events, such as clicks, etc.
initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods
        console.log(this);
         this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
      },
      // `render()`: Function in charge of rendering the entire view in `this.el`. Needs to be manually called by the user.
      render: function(){
    console.log(this);
        $(this.el).append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
      }
    });

    // **listView instance**: Instantiate main app view.
    var listView = new ListView();
  })(jQuery);
```

if I access this using file:///C:/Users/usr/Desktop/backbone/index.html, this.el is undefined. why?

If I copy paste the same code in jsfiddle its working. not sure why[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your javascript code is being executed prior to the body tag existing in your html document. Put your script tags directly before the closing body tag, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- content here -->  

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested this and it works for me with your javascript file

Comment: You could also replace `el: $('body')` with `el: 'body'` (which is much better anyway IMO).

Comment: it is true that you can do that, and that it is a better way of doing it, but that wasn't the problem. I changed his code to read the way you describe and the problem still existed